# Should I expose the BlackBerry networking configuration settings to the end user?

Tags: networking, blackberry

When using the networking API in BB OS 5.0 (ConnectionFactory, etc.) there are a ton of options for configuring the connection.  How much of this is it appropriate/expected to expose to the end user of the application?

Certainly, I will be setting what I think are appropriate defaults for my application, but some things (e.g. preferred and disallowed transports) seem like they are questions that the user can or should answer.

Is there any kind of best practice here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is one of the things I dislike in BB development - you never know what type of connectivity a BB user has on the device. As a result the code to detect a usable transport is complicated (even despite RIM has [some sample code](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/What-Is-Network-API-alternative-for-legacy-OS/ta-p/614822) on how to do this).

In the apps development I've been involved in there were different approaches to this. However each app had networking settings which were implied to be populated by user.

For instance, one app asks user to select a transport type on app startup. :) This is definitelly an ideal solution for developers, but not for users (they simply may not know what the "network transport" is). If the target audience mostly consists of advanced users, then this will work good.

Another approach is to use some code to auto-detect a usable transport type, however this approach may also fail (for instance, if the code tries to cover a wide range of OS versions and device makes, then there are most likely will be some unexpected exclusions). So as a fallback scenario it is good to have some networking settings screen where user could check what transports to use (maybe just the only one) and APN settings.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the target audience. You could do a simplified view with basic options and and advanced view with every thing under the sun that is configurable with a reset button in case the user gets lost.

Comment: So a simple screen (or no screen?) for "Joe BB User" who just wants the thing to work and a more advanced screen for "Jane BB PowerUser" who only wants the app to use WiFi, thank-you-very-much?

Comment: yeah, something like that. For example Chrome has three levels; First is Basic Settings, second is "Under the hood" and third is all the `about:***` pages like `about:cache` , `about:plugins` .